# Select first 200 vectors in R

Tags: r

sorry if this is a total newbie question but I am new to R (and coding in general).

I'm trying to plot a linear regression by selecting only the first 200 vector values of my data set (it has 400). How do I do this? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried, where are you stuck, share your research. Low effort questions are discouraged here. [Read here, how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and don't worry about the downvotes. It's not personal, just criticism of your questions quality. Happens to everyone at first.

Answer (score 2):

Convenient function would be `head`

```
head(vec, n=200)
```

returns the first 200 elements of the vector ('vec') object

Similarly, `tail` returns the last 'n' elements

```
tail(vec, n=200)
```

---

In addition, to remove the first n elements use `tail` with `n` as negative value

```
tail(vec, n=-200)
```

and for last n elements

```
head(vec, n=-200)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your dataset is 'df':

```
smaller_df <- df[1:200,]
```

If you need help to fit the model and plot it, add your code!